# PHP SQL query not returning same rows as in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is a query run in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT app . * 
FROM  `tap_applications` app,  `tap_jobs` job
WHERE job.id = app.job_id
AND job.closed =0
AND job.user_id =1
```

This returns five rows (`Showing rows 0 - 4 ( 5 total, Query took 0.0008 sec)`) and I can see that the rows are correct.

Here is my PHP code executing the query:

```
$id=1;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT app.* 
                         FROM `tap_applications` app, `tap_jobs` job 
                        WHERE job.id = app.job_id
                          AND job.closed = 0
                          AND job.user_id=?');
if($stmt->execute(array($id))){
    $apps = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($apps); exit();
}
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [job_id] => 6
    [name1] => Ben
    [name2] => //redacted
    [tel] => //redacted
    [email] => //redacted
    [cv] => 6-Ben1424692150.pdf
    [seen] => 0
    [time] => 2015-02-23 11:57:33
    [decision] => 1
)
```

Why is this not outputting all the rows returned by the SQL query?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php : PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set.

Comment: Try to use fetchAll function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line below only fetches 1 row:

```
$apps = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Use `fetchAll` instead:

```
$apps = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```